# How do I find the fixed points of this 2-d map?

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, bifurcation

> Consider the two-dimensional map
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
>  X_{n+1} &= X_n + Y_n + r\left(X_n - X^3_n\right)\\
>  Y_{n+1} &= Y_n + r\left(X_n - X^3_n\right)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>   where $r$ is a control parameter. Find the fixed points of this map as a function of the control parameter $0 < r < 4$.

How do you find the fixed points of this map? I have no idea here how to proceed when there is a cubic term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a $2$D map $\begin{cases}x_{n+1}=f(x_n,y_n)\\y_{n+1}=g(x_n,y_n)\end{cases}$ the fixed point (or, *critical point*) are given by solution of the system of equation $\begin{cases}f(x,y)=x\\g(x,y)=y\end{cases}.$

Comment: Yes, Same result holds for me. I think in your discrete map the fixed are not depend on control parameter $r$.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed point are $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$.

Comment: Yes I made the mistake also.